# Convert old Code Help. VB6 (I think) to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, legacy

I have tried follow this through, but I am struggling to get it into C#.

```
Private Function TransmitHex(nChar As Byte, nOption As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim sHex As String
    Dim nHi As Byte
    Dim nLo As Byte

    sHex = Right("00" + Hex(nChar), 2)

    nHi = AscW(Left$(sHex, 1))
    nLo = AscW(Right$(sHex, 1))

    Comm.Output = ChrW$(nHi)

    Comm.Output = ChrW$(nLo)

End Function
```

I have 2 bytes that I think are passed into here. 4 and 176. I can't run the code either.

Can anyone tell me what the equivalent C# would be? Or just explain what happens to nChar on the way through. Many thanks!

Comment: If you don't have VB6, you could paste the code into a VBA macro and execute it that way to follow it through yourself.

Comment: The code converts `nChar` into a 2-digit hexadecimal representation of the byte value. Then it sends the two digits to the `Com` object (the serial port?). The `nOption` argument is completely ignored. The use of `AscW` and `ChrW` is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public bool TransmitHex(byte char, bool opt)
{
    //convert to chat to a hex string and that to an array of chars
    var hex = char.ToString("X2").ToCharArray();
    //open a connection to a serialport
    var sp = new SerialPort("COM1");
    //write the hex vals
    sp.Write(hex,0,1);
    sp.Write(hex,1,1);
    return true;
}
```